# FeatherActivity is not being initiallzed with Aviary-SDK (NoClassDefFoundError)

Tags: android, aviary

The thing is that I want to implement Aviary-SDK in order to have this activity that edit pictures.

The thing is that the project doesn't show any mistake but while launching it I find this error:

10-25 11:05:05.082: E/AndroidRuntime(21217): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.aviary.android.feather.FeatherActivity

I am sure this is a thing of libraries because I have already done it in a test, but while implementing it in the main project I am having this problem.

[image: Library aviary sdk]

[image]

Thank you very much

Comment: This could help you - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Answer (score 0):

Try checked **Android Dependencies**

[image]

Comment: It is all checked, I have updated the post with the image I have.

Comment: Hvae you checked for android support v4 library because aviry sdk has used old library instead new, so you need to make two android support v4 library same in your project and aviary sdk